# How do I get a Linux kernel binary file?

Tags: linux-kernel

I have downloaded the latest kernel from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org) . What I want is to compile it to get the executable file. I need the file to run some commands on it (like strings) to figure what how to identify the linux kernel from its binary file.
All the tutorials on the internet are for upgrading/changing the kernel but I only want the binary file.

Comment: If you want the binary file, then you have to compile the kernel for the target architecture in which you want to execute it. That requires several steps. Please check [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html) for guidance.

Comment: You may take one from the running system (usually in */boot* folder somewhere). But kernel image has few stages and it's compressed. So, it's not so easy to simple identify by running `strings` over it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want are vmlinux and *.ko elf files, but you must compile your kernel first. The bzImage is compressed so you cannot run strings on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the kernel under `\boot`. Should be called something like `vmlinuz*`